# Threading & locks in java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I heard that every object in java has an intrinsic lock associated with it. what if a thread take this lock to invoke synchronized method. does that mean no another thread can access any methods in this object or the synchronized methods only ?!

Comment: Have y9ou considered consulting the documentation? Instead of relying on what you 'heard'? or can find here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one thread can access synchronized methods at the same time.

See [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html):

> First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

Comment: but other threads can access unsynchronized methods at the same time when the thread access synchronized method ?!

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` on an instance method is shorthand for `synchronized (this) { }` around the entire method body. For static methods it is the equivalent of `synchronized (this.class) { }`. So just think `synchronized (obj) { }`.

Only a single thread can acquire a lock, so superficially only one thread can enter at a time. Loser threads *block* until the lock is available.

That's not the entire story. If somewhere within a `synchronized` block (perhaps in another method) the thread calls `this.wait();` (with optional arguments), then that thread releases the lock for the duration of `wait()`. During this time the lock is available, for instance, to call `this.notifyAll()`.

Also it worth noting that the lock is reentrant. Another, or the same, `synchronized` method can be called recursively.

Comment: when it return from waiting what if another thread has the lock !

Comment: It waits until the other thread releases the lock and this one has acquired it before return from `wait`